# How to get the value of selected item on change using jQueryUI Selectenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I am using the Select Menu widget to display a list of states within a form:

```
<select name="state" id="state">
   <option value = "">Select State</option>
   <option value = "Alabama">Alabama</option>
   <option value= "Alaska">Alaska</option>
   <option value= "Arizona">Arizona</option>
   <option value= "California">California</option>
   <option value= "Colorado">Colorado</option>
   <option value= "Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
 </select>
```

In my script I have

```
 $( "#state" ).selectmenu();
```

Now, what I am trying to do is send out an alert of the value of the selected option.  So I have this:

```
$('select').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    alert(valueSelected);
});
```

The issue is that for some reason none of that is working when I use the JQueryUI function `selectmenu()`

When I remove that one line, everything functions as normal. It was my understanding that I need to include  `$( "#state" ).selectmenu();` in order to utilize the JQuery UI theme and functionality.

Can anyone enlighten me on what the issue may be.  Again, it works fine if I remove that selectmenu line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

jQuery UI hides your original `<select>` and creates custom widjets using dynamically injected elements. So you are no longer clicking on the original `<option>`'s you provided, and no `change` event will be triggered on it.

Instead, it emits a `selectmenuchange` event when the selected item is changed . You can listen to it by passing the handler function to the [`change`](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectmenu/#event-change) option while initializing the plugin.

The `item` property of second argument passed to the callback function refers to the item you've selected. You can access it's value as shown below:

```js
$("#state").selectmenu({
  change: function(event, ui) {
    alert(ui.item.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<select name="state" id="state">
  <option value="">Select State</option>
  <option value="Alabama">Alabama</option>
  <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
  <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>
  <option value="California">California</option>
  <option value="Colorado">Colorado</option>
  <option value="Connecticut">Connecticut</option>
</select>
```

---

You can also manually listen to this event like:

```
$('select').on('selectmenuchange', function (e,ui) {
   alert(ui.item.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the selectmenu with the select callback specified:

Try this.

```
$( "#state" ).selectmenu({
  select: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Or You might be using an older version of the `jquery-ui` plugin. please check if it supports the `selectmenu` plugin.

try the following.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey Ronny - I tried that and it still doesn't make the select script work :/  Should I be putting the script within the select: function( event, ui ) {} braces?

Comment: I changed the JQuery-UI link and it still doesn't work.  I am linking my theme to <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery_ui/jquery-ui.min.css"> and I am linking the JQuery to <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">

Comment: The theme is showing up properly with the select menu, the functionality is just not working.  You can see the issue at: http://secretswith.me/newindex.php    - The select menu without the JQuery UI checks the database and displays properly.  The one with the UI doesn't.